# "Alternative to" vs "Alternative for"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, determiners

I'm wondering whether there is a difference between these two expressions. I never know which one to use. Google seems to return the same amount of results for both, so I suppose there might be a difference.

> 1. What are the alternatives for this project?
> 2. What are the alternatives to this project?

Comment: Well, if we search our own little site, the verdict is pretty clear: [71 hits for "alternative to"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22alternative+to%22+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com), and [2 hits for "alternative for"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22alternative+for%22+site%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com). (^_^)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To me these two statements have different meanings.

> What are the alternatives to this project?

This means "What other projects could we do instead?"

> What are the alternatives for this project?

This means "In the context of this project, what choices do we have about how to solve it?